# Solution to In App Purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, soomla

I need create In App Purchase function cocos2dx my project. 
Soomla is a good solution but soomla not support cocos2dx 3.3.

Can you give me a other solution?

Answer (score 0):

EasyNdk or JNI has to be used to call natively function.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the latest version of Soomla does support cocos2d-x 3.4